# rails 4 bootstrap modal flashes briefly before showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

When I click on my "pin"'s image it popsup(over?) a modal. But, the modal flashes briefly before it actually shows itself. You can see this at [omrails.herokuapp.com](http://omrails.herokuapp.com). How can I fix this behaviour?

I have the following code,

app/views/pins/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@pin.image.url(:medium)),"#pinsmodal", data: {toggle: "modal", trigger: "#pinsmodal"} %>
...
<div class="modal fade" id="pinsmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modallabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
```

app/assets/javascripts/pins.coffee

```
...
$ ->
$('#pinsmodal').on 'shown.bs.modal', (click) ->
    $('#pinsmodal').modal('show')
...
```

Comment: Please provide login informations, I assume the problem is after login and I think we dont want to create registrations in (iam sorry) unsecured page :) thanks

Comment: no need to login. just click the pin that's already there to be taken to the show view then click it again to activate the modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so combined with what Alex Veremeenko contributed and some searching I found the reason for the flashing was because of the following lines in application.js

```
...
//=require bootstrap-sprockets
//=require bootstrap
...
```

Something about a double call. I removed the line

```
//=require bootstrap-sprockets
```

and all works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your coffee script means - if modal is shown - show it again.
Remove it at all. And all will works fine.

Comment: Hi Alex and thanks for replying. If I do as you instructed then the modal just flashes quickly and disappears upon activation.